# Form submit display new page only when it has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 web pages

On my index page I have a form which calls my second page which contains php and javascript etc.

Is it possible to keep the index page showing until the second page has loaded after the form has been submitted? or something that will achieve a similar result.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's `.post` function for this.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**Example:**

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

You can use `.html` to display the data https://api.jquery.com/html/.

Note: You can't run the js from test.php on the main page. If you want to achieve this. A solution is to include the javascript on the mainpage instead of the second page.

Comment: Thanks, I should have built it this way in the first place.